# How to set specify encryption hash when creating Linux user?

Tags: linux, password, hash

I want to create a few Linux user on my computer to test JohnTheRipper against different kind of password (including length, charset and encryption hash method). How can I easily specify which hashing algorithm to use when creating a new user ? I know that the file /etc/login.defs contains the variable ENCRYPT_METHOD which is set to SHA512 by default on many Debian system but I would know if it is possible to use another encryption hash without modifying this file.

ps: I tried to modify this file, rebooting and create a new user with command adduser but the encryption hash method user is always the SHA512

thanks

Comment: sudo echo "$user:`/lib/cryptsetup/askpass 'Enter Password:'`" | sudo time chpasswd --crypt-method SHA512 --sha-rounds 1000000`

Comment: Specify $user and make sure you have sudo first. Warning! There's no password verification so make sure you have another root terminal open somewhere just in case.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest method to set a up a password with a non-default hashing method is to manually hash the password first and then supply that password when setting up the user:

```
 adduser --password HASHEDPASSWORD user
```

Where the HASHEDPASSWORD must follow your system's standards for the `crypt` function (`man 3 crypt`):

> If salt is a character string starting with the characters  "$id$"  followed  by  a string terminated by `"$"`:
>
> ```
>          $id$salt$encrypted
> ```
>
> then instead of using the DES machine, id identifies the encryption method used and this then determines how the rest of the password string is interpreted.  The  following values of id are supported:
>
> ```
>           ID  | Method
>           ---------------------------------------------------------
>           1   | MD5
>           2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
>               | Linux distributions)
>           5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
>           6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
> ```
>
> So  `$5$salt$encrypted`  is  an  SHA-256 encoded password and `$6$salt$encrypted` is an SHA-512 encoded one.

To generate a correct hash from the commandline you can look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52108).

Comment: Thank for the reference to the other post. It is helpful. But your example with add user doesn't work on my host because --password is an unknow option.

Comment: That may depend on the Linux distro, I'm most familiar with RHEL/CentOS.  Maybe `usermod`?

Comment: It is working if I use mkpassword tool, and copy and past the output to /etc/shadow for the corresponding user. I will test it and edit my response

Answer (score 0):

After some test, the best way to create different users with different hash algorithm is composed of 3 steps:

1. Create the user without password
2. Create the UNIX format password using specified parameters (salt, password, hashing algorithm)
3. Set the generated UNIX password in /etc/shadow

Here an example of a user **test1**, with password **1234** and **md5** as hashing function.

`sudo adduser test1 --disabled-password
sudo mkpasswd --method=md5 --salt=coolsalt 1234
$1$coolsalt$qTXiZzGn08J.xYkV1ce1y1`

and now, just edit the **/etc/shadow**

**Before editing**
`test1:*:16559:0:99999:7:::`

**After editing**
`test1:$1$coolsalt$qTXiZzGn08J.xYkV1ce1y1:16559:0:99999:7:::`

After, you can try to login with this user to check if the format is corect.

`whoami
root
su test1
Password: 1234
whoami
test1`

Thanks for the help